# panorama control with scroll

Tags: c#, button, layout, windows-phone-8, scrollview

I'm really new to programming but decided I will start learning c# development for windows phone 8. I know they have a button control in the toolbox but I am looking to make the kind of buttons you see on the start screen for the phone. No idea how.

Also I would love to know how to use the panorama control and how to incorporate the buttons asks previously to have an image and put into a verticals scroll layout, separated by panorama items of course. Please note as I said before I'm super new and don't know much yet.

Answer (score 0):

To make start screen buttons alike (a.k.a tiles) take a look [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/). Download the examples and look under `HubTile`.

Now for the second part of your question all you need is a panorama page with a `WrapPanel`that can also be found in the [toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) mentioned earlier.

So what you should be doing is adding a `WrapPanel` inside the PanoramaItem, and then the `HubTiles` inside the wrap panel. Here is an example:

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="hubtiles"> 
    <Grid>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <toolkit:HubTile/> <!-- Change accordingly -->
        </toolkit:WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
```